# Kronecker's Jugendtraum for $p$-adic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is there a construction of maximal abelian extensions of $p$-adic fields by adjunction of special points of $p$-adic analytic varieties (e.g., torsion points of abelian varieties) along the lines of Kronecker's Jugendtraum (Hilbert's 12th problem) for number fields which is fully realized only for $\mathbb{Q}$ and its imaginary quadratic extensions.

Comment: Well, there’s Lubin-Tate theory...

Comment: There are also some recent results by Darmon and Vonk. See 69 and 72 in http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/pub.html

Comment: Note that the natural analogue of Kronecker jugentraum is to construct abelian extensions of numbet fields by p-adic analytic functions, not of p-adic fields, which is what Lubin-Tate theory solves masterfully.